# Can createTopic in kafka work for the same topic name existence

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying createTopic() for kafka. The problem is, it does not fail for the same name topic existence. I am not able to locate any settings to control this.. whats the inherit behavior?

Comment: If you are saying AdminUtils.createTopic, this method does complain the presence of the same name topic.

Comment: what about kafka-topics.sh --create

Comment: Same. TopicExistsException will be thrown if creating an already-exist topic.